# node_save does not save language

Tags: 7, nodes

I cannot programmatically create a node in anything other than `en` language.

My site has 3 languages:

- en
- fr
- de

And the code for creating a node is:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', ...); 
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . 'includes/bootstrap.inc'; 
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); 

$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = "foobar";
node_object_prepare($node);
$node->title = 'test title';
$node->uid = 1;
$node->language = 'fr'; // *** this doesn't seem to work

if ($node = node_submit($node)) {
  node_save($node);
}
```

No matter what I type in the `$node->language = '...';` the result is always the same. The node is created in the English language. I confirm that via looking at `admin/content`.

I've even tried stuffing this variable with a proper language object which I got out of the enabled languages of my site:

```
$languages = language_list('enabled');
$lang = $languages[1]['de'];
$node->language = $lang;
```

Comment: As side note, `node_submit()` always returns the parameter passed to the function; there is no need to check the value returned from the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior was an unfortunate side-effect of the `admin_language` module and the setting `Force use of default language`.

The "offending" code is at http://drupalcode.org/project/admin_language.git/blob/0167e36c45661502ee6907a5b2b7cad8538b19cf:/admin_language.module#l112

Disabling this options solves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Some of the hooks might not be firing, instead of `node_save($node)`, try `drupal_execute($form_id, $form_state)`

That last link was bad... lullabot's should help:

http://www.lullabot.com/articles/quick-and-dirty-cck-imports

doh... drupal 7. Looks like they have changed it to `drupal_form_submit`

http://www.lukaswhite.com/blog/post/2011/drupal-7-drupal_execute-has-gone-say-hello-to-drupal_form_submit

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've seen that sometimes people do suggest `drupal_form_submit` instead of `node_save` but I'd really like to know if and how this simple task (saving non English) can be achieved with `node_save`.