# i18n - Not translating Menu's or Blocks

Tags: i18n-l10n

## The Problem

Using the i18n module, node translations are working, however *Menu* and *Block* translations are not showing up.

For example: I created 2 identical blocks. For one i set the *Show this block for these languages* to English and the other to Bulgarian. When i then go mysite.com it shows me the English block, but when i go to mysite.com/bg it still shows me the English block.

I have also tried the *Make this block translatable* but that doesn't work either.

## The setup

**Drupal version:** 7.14

**Related modules:** i18n (all enabled apart from Multilingual Forum), pathauto, localization update, administration language, locale

## Background

This is my first Drupal 7 website. The website im working on is a multilingual, multi-country website which is near completion. Hopefully that gives some idea of my exerpience, so if you could tailor your answers to that please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work in "Make this block translatable"?

Comment: Well i checked the box, i added translations for each language, went to the page and it wasn't translating it.

Comment: Are you sure you where not seeing that previous version of the English block that you mention in your question?

Comment: Right so i've now hidden the Bulgarian copy of the block i created (in the block list), and gone into the English block. I have unchecked all the language fields and checked *Make this block translatable*. I have then gone to the *Translate* tab in the block and created a translation for Bulgaria. Then i went to my website and using the Language Switcher selected Bulgaria. On the page i can see translated versions of my nodes, but the block still shows the English copy.

Comment: So do you confirm that it doesn't work if you create a new block, make it translatable and translate it?

Comment: Yes. I can confirm that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that encounter this issue, the problem is being caused by another module. Disabling the below module fixed the issue.

[Drupal 7 - Admin Language Module](http://drupal.org/project/admin_language)

Comment: I had a similar side effect with this module at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37967/node-save-does-not-save-language

Answer (score 7):

if anyone else is experiencing this issue, notice that it can also be caused by your configuration in *yoursite/admin/config/regional/language/configure*, even if you are not using [Admin Language Module](http://drupal.org/project/admin_language).

Menus are part of your interface, not of content. So, for example, if you set your interface language detection to default (only use site default language), because you want your interface to be only in english, you are not going to see your translated menu blocks when you navigate to *yoursite/anotherlanguage*!

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: `Menus are part of your interface, not of content.` - wow - ok - ofcourse - thanks

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check regarding menu items being translated or not. Make sure that your menus are not themed via CSS with images that contain a specific language.